# Add maximumIntegerDigits option in the Intl.NumberFormat function in javascript

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I have a react component which formats a currency using `Intl.NumberFormat` javascript function

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const Amount = ({
  value,
  currency,
  locale,
  className,
  maxFractionDigit,
  minFractionDigit,
  notation,
  compactDisplay,
}) => {
  const amount = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency,
    currencySign: 'standard',
    notation,
    compactDisplay,
    maximumFractionDigits: maxFractionDigit,
    minimumFractionDigits: minFractionDigit,
  }).format(value);

  return <span className={classNames(className)}>{amount}</span>;
};

Amount.defaultProps = {
  locale: 'en-US',
  className: null,
  maxFractionDigit: 2,
  minFractionDigit: 0,
  notation: 'compact',
  compactDisplay: 'short',
};

Amount.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
  currency: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  locale: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.node]),
  className: PropTypes.string,
  maxFractionDigit: PropTypes.number,
  minFractionDigit: PropTypes.number,
  notation: PropTypes.oneOf(['standard', 'scientific', 'engineering', 'compact']),
  compactDisplay: PropTypes.oneOf(['short', 'long']),
};

export default Amount;
```

it formats a given currency i.e: if the input is `123456.5556` the output is `$123.46K` but now I want to change the max integer digits to show upto 6 so if the input is `123456.5556` the output always will be `123456.5556`. e.g: there will not be any `K` notation, so the minimum truncation will be from `M` not `K`. so for input `1234567.5556` output will be `$1.23M`, I went through the doc here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat but did not find any option like `maximumIntegerDigits`, so how can I achieve this using the current code.

Comment: @JaromandaX it is automatically done by `compactDisplay` `notation` argument in the `Intl.NumberFormat` function which is a default of Javascript, here is the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Comment: Sorry, I misread ... so you want 123456.5556 to be 123456.5556 - then don't use notation compact unless amount > 999999.99999 .... i.e. i.e. `notation: value < 1e6 ? 'standard' : 'compact'`